# during first cypress run getting error spawn EPERM on Windows

Tags: cypress

C:\Users\rXXXX\automationlearning\node_modules.bin>cypress open
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 3.4.1

×  Verifying Cypress can run C:\Users\rXXXXX\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\3.4.1\Cypress
   → Cypress Version: 3.4.1
Cypress failed to start.

This is usually caused by a missing library or dependency.

The error below should indicate which dependency is missing.

https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.

---

spawn EPERM

---

Platform: win32 (10.0.17134)
Cypress Version: 3.4.1

I expect UE should be opened

Comment: How do you using cypress locally? How did you try to open? Do you have package.json in your project? Have you ran npm install and npm run cypress: open?

Comment: Yes .I had executed npm init to create package json and then installed cypress with npm command but when I try to open in .bin . it shows above errors